# Finding of dimension of algebraic varieties

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebra, computational-geometry, high-dimensional-geometry

I have found that the problem of finding of dimension of algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ is $NP$-complete (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a947/463a29ee512b89823176f6e8c9f9b2bb1a5e.pdf).

Are there the similar results about dimensions of algebraic varieties over finite fields?